# Running a procedure in all databases

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I've created a system stored procedure in the `Master` database which can be run in all databases. I want to run it in all databases at once, here what I use:

```
use Master
GO

declare @sql nvarchar(1000)

SET @sql = 'USE [?]; EXEC [dbo].[sp_procedure]'

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @sql
```

The problem is - not all databases have have similar table and column structure. So inside procedure, I do this before doing any calculations:

```
if exists(select 1 
          from 
              INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES b,
              INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
          where 
              b.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' 
              and b.TABLE_NAME = 'tablename'
              and c.TABLE_NAME = b.TABLE_NAME
              and c.COLUMN_NAME = 'columnname')
```

So, if while running across all databases, there is no table named 'tablename' with column name 'columnname' it should skip procedure for that database and go on to the next database. I have a database which has 'tablename' table, but doesn't have 'columnname' column in this table, and it returns this error:

> Invalid column name 'columnname'.

Why that `if exists` statement goes inside if statement? Shouldn't it terminate as soon as condition is not met? How can I handle this situation?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because SQL Engine tries to compile the code, so it checks the code inside IF block.

You have to use that comparison outside the stored procedure, e.g. in your SET @sql = '......' command, but it will not run that SP if the column does not exist.

So you can try something else - build the query (nvarchar variable) inside the SP and execute it as dynamic SQL.

Comment: Exactly. Thanks, @Anton